# Redirecting output to a text file located on Azure Storage - Using Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-blob-storage

Using PowerShell, what is the best way of writing output to a text file located on Azure storage container? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply, you can't.

While this capability exists within Azure Storage with the (relatively) new [Append blob](http://blogs.technet.com/b/thbrown/archive/2015/08/26/azure-blob-now-has-append.aspx) it hasn't yet filtered down to Powershell.

In order to implement this you would either need to create a new c# cmdlet that encapsulates the functionality. Or you will need to redirect the output to a standard file and then us the usual Azure storage cmdlets to upload  that file to Azure Storage.